# Simplification for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi guys I was wondering if it is possible to somehow convert the form $\operatorname{cis}(\theta)$ to the form $(-1)^x$. Is there an algebraic method for this? If so what is it called?

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $(-1)^x$ is not well-defined unless $x$ is an integer, in which case the result is always $1$ or $-1$. So for most $\theta$s this is not possible.

Does it do at least some of what you want to write $\operatorname{cis}(\theta) = e^{i\theta}$?

Unfortunately the rule $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ doesn't work when there are complex numbers around (except, again, when $b$ and $c$ are both integers), so we cannot rewrite $e^{i\theta}$ further to $(e^i)^\theta$.

Comment: What about this, apparently, (-1)^(2/5) = cis(2pi/5), how can I for example change cis(4pi/5) in this form

Comment: @user2250537: $(-1)^{2/5}$ is not a well defined notation.

Comment: I know but is there a way to algebraically transform cis(theta) to such a form of notation ?

Comment: Or try and solve the following problem, prove that (-1)^(2/5) = cis(2pi/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes play games using $e^{i\pi} = -1$. For example,

$\operatorname{cis}(\frac {3 \pi}2) = e^{\frac {3i\pi} 2} = (e^{i\pi})^{\frac 3 2} = (-1)^{\frac 3 2}$

However, depending on context, expressions like $(-1)^{\frac 3 2}$ might be multivalued, so be careful.

Comment: This depends on $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ which is not necessarily true when $b$ is complex.

Comment: Surely it works for all $b,c \in \mathbb C$ for $a = e$?

Comment: x @GFa: No, consider $-1 = e^{\pi i}=e^{2\pi i\frac 12}\ne (e^{2\pi i})^{1/2} = 1^{1/2} = 1 $.

Comment: Hence what I meant when I said that the expression might be multivalued. $1^{1/2}$, when considering the roots of unity for example, has two solutions.